# SQL Server - Count characters between two characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

How would one count the number of letters (alphabetically a to z or z to a) between two characters?

For example:

```
WITH    ExampleData
          AS ( SELECT   'a' AS StartChar, 'e' AS EndChar
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   'm', 'r'
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   'f', 'a'
             )
    SELECT  StartChar ,
            EndChar
    FROM    ExampleData
```

Would need to produce:

```
StartChar   EndChar    Diff
a           e          4
m           r          5
f           a          -5
```

I see how this could easily be done using udf's and a while loop but I was wondering if there was a faster way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT StartChar, EndChar, ASCII(EndChar) - ASCII(StartChar) AS Diff
FROM ExampleData
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/898)

Comment: lol, A definite "Why didn’t i think of this" answer (long day - too little coffee)

Comment: I'd like some coffee too. It's a requriement for a good job! :D

Comment: Usually all it takes is another pair of eyes or another cup of coffee, often both.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you've already done validity checks on StartChar and EndChar...

```
SELECT ASCII(EndChar) - ASCII(StartChar) as Diff
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get the job done for you:

```
WITH    ExampleData
          AS ( SELECT   'a' AS StartChar, 'e' AS EndChar
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   'm', 'r'
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   'f', 'a'
             )
    SELECT  StartChar ,
            EndChar, ascii(EndChar) - ascii(StartChar) as Diff
    FROM    ExampleData
```

Answer (score 0):

CTE is just awesome! This way you can do that if you won't want to use ASCII:

```
;   With    CharCodes   (
    Code
)   As          (
    Select  65
Union   All
    Select  Code
    +   1
        From    CharCodes
        Where   Code        <   90
)
    Select  Second.Code
    -   First.Code
        From    CharCodes   As  First
        ,   CharCodes   As  Second
        Where   First.Code  =   Convert(Int, Convert(VarBinary, 'A'))
        And Second.Code =   Convert(Int, Convert(VarBinary, 'E'))
```

And using the ASCII function you can do it this way:

```
Select  ASCII('E')
-   ASCII('A')
```

Comment: Why would you wan to go the first route in your example? It seems overly busy for a simple task

Comment: Where ever you loose something you earn something else. It seems busy but I prefer to do that in some situations. It depends on many conditions. ;)